# If I eager load associated child records, then that means future WHERE retrievals won't dig through database again?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

Just trying to understand... if at the start of some method I eager load a record and its associated children like this:

```
@object = Object.include(:children).where(email:"test@example.com").first
```

Then does that mean that if later I have to look through that object's children this will not generate more database queries?

I.e.,

```
@found_child = @object.children.where(type_of_child:"this type").first
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not - using ActiveRecord::Relation methods such as `where` will query the database again.

You could however filter the data without any further queries, using the standard Array / Enumerable methods:

```
@object.children.detect {|child| child.type_of_child == "this type"}
```

Comment: ah I was afraid of this... the reason I'm still using `where` is because the full statement reads `@object.children.where(type_of_child: "this type").pluck(:amount).inject(:+)`, but I don't think I can use standard Array methods to duplicate that right?

Comment: you'd use nap rather than pluck but it would be pretty much the same

Answer (score 0):

It will generate another database query in your case.

Eager loading is used to avoid N+1 queries. This is done by loading all associated objects. But this doesn't work when you want to filter that list with `where` later on, Rails will than build a new query and run that one.

That said: In your example the `include` makes your code actually slower, because it loads associated object, but cannot use them.

I would change your example to:

```
@object = Object.find_by(email: "test@example.com")
@found_child = @object.children.find_by(type_of_child: "this type")
```